# Delete rows that match pattern by id

Tags: bash, shell

I have the following file containing *n* rows:

```
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
>name.1_i1_xyz_n
>name.1_i1_xyz_n
>name.1_i1_xyz_m
>name.1_i2_xyz_n
>name.1_i2_xyz_m
>name.1_i7_xyz_m
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
...
```

I want to delete rows that ends with `m`. In the example the output would be:

```
>name.1_i4_n
>name.1_i4_n
...
```

Note that I've deleted `i2` as it has two records and **one of them ends with `m`**. Same with `i1`.

Any help? I want to keep it simple and do it with just one line of code.
This is what I have so far:

```
$ grep "i._.*." < input.txt | sort -k 2 -t "_" | cut -d'_' -f1,2,4
>name.1_i1_m
>name.1_i1_n
>name.1_i1_n
>name.1_i2_m
>name.1_i2_n
>name.1_i4_n
>name.1_i4_n
>name.1_i7_m
...
```

Comment: yes, all of them start with `>`

Comment: Or to put it another way you want _i4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `i...` part does not appear in any other column, you can use

```
grep -vFf <(grep -E 'm$' file | cut -d _ -f 2) file
```

The part inside `<()` filters out all `i...` that have a row ending with `m`. In your example: `i1`, `i2`, and `i7`.

The outer `grep` takes a list of literal search strings (inside the `<()`) and prints only the lines not containing any of the search strings.

Comment: @anubhava That's why I wrote »*If the i... part does not appear in any other column*«.

Answer (score 2):

<s>*to delete rows that ends with* m:</s>

```
$ grep -v m$ file
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
>name.1_i1_xyz_n
>name.1_i1_xyz_n
>name.1_i2_xyz_n
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
```

Another solution that handles the ids, using awk and 2 runs:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS="_" }  # set delimiter
NR==FNR {                # on the first run 
    if($0~/m$/)          # if it ends in an m
        d[$2]            # make a del array entry of that index
    next
}
($2 in d==0)' file file  # on the second run don't print if index in del array
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
```

One-liner version:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"}NR==FNR{if($0~/m$/)d[$2];next}($2 in d==0)' file file
```

Comment: but all the rows which contains `i1` should be deleted too, as there's one row whose id is `i1` and ends with `m` (same with `i2`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` as this:

```
awk -F_ '{if(/m$/) a[$2]; else rows[++n]=$0}
END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {split(rows[i], b, FS); if (!(b[2] in a)) print}}' file

>name.1_i4_xyz_n
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk proposal.

```
awk '/_i4/&&!/_m$/' filterm.awk

>name.1_i4_xyz_n
>name.1_i4_xyz_n
```